# Python: How can I restart a method without capturing any values?

Tags: python, methods, nonetype

I created a Rock, Paper, Scissors game in Python, but I had trouble restarting the method if the player typed an invalid command. If the user types anything other than an 'r', 'p', or 's' the first time it asks, the value None will always be returned when a proper value is entered. I found I could just restart the round, but when I added a wager to the game it proved to be an inconvenience.

```
def get_input():
    choice = input("[R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors? ").lower()
    if choice == 'r':
        return 'rock'
    elif choice == 'p':
        return 'paper'
    elif choice == 's':
        return 'scissors'
    else:
        print("That is not a valid command. Try again.")
        get_input()

choice = get_input()
print(choice)
```

The output when the user types an 'a' followed by a 'p':

[R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors? a
That is not a valid command. Try again.
[R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors? p
None

Comment: Worth noting, you are not "restarting" your method, you are _recursing_ into your method.  You should consider a `while choice not in 'rps':` loop instead - with your current approach a user could enter invalid values until they overran the recursion buffer and cause your program to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your current code, you should `return` the value.

```
def get_input():
    choice = input("[R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors? ").lower()
    if choice == 'r':
        return 'rock'
    elif choice == 'p':
        return 'paper'
    elif choice == 's':
        return 'scissors'
    else:
        print("That is not a valid command. Try again.")
        return get_input()
#       ^^^^^^

choice = get_input()
print(choice)
```

However, if the user provides too many incorrect inputs, the stack will end up growing too large. What you want is a loop:

```
def get_input():
    while True:
        choice = input("[R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors? ").lower()
        if choice == 'r':
            return 'rock'
        elif choice == 'p':
            return 'paper'
        elif choice == 's':
            return 'scissors'
        # go through the loop again.

choice = get_input()
print(choice)
```

Comment: could you extend the answer to show OP how it should be done? Recurrent calls on incorrect input is not the way to go to handle input.

Comment: Good idea. I'll do it

Comment: This is an awful way to do it - what is wrong with a while loop - and looping until a valid input. Using recursion to validate is awful .

Comment: It's k i changed it br0

Answer (score 3):

When validating text input from an interactive shell, I recommend using a loop:

```
def get_input():
    while True:
        choice = input("[R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors? ").lower()
        if choice == 'r':
            return 'rock'
        elif choice == 'p':
            return 'paper'
        elif choice == 's':
            return 'scissors'
        else:
            print("That is not a valid command. Try again.")
```

Note that it is OK to use `while True` in Python, because there is no `do ... while`. If there should only be a limited number of retries, you could use `for _ in range(num_retries)`.